# How to include a file in Javascript and Jsp?

Tags: javascript, jsp, include

Ok,i know in Php you can use include for a Php file...for example...

```
include("array.php");
```

Is there a way to do this in Javascript and Jsp?

From what i read i cant use for example `include("array.javascript");` or `include("array.jsp");`

I want to load the array from a different file and i know how to do it with Php,but not with Javascript or Jsp. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused, JSP is an XML-based language executed at the server side that gets transformed into Java the first time is processed by the servlet container (server) whilst JavaScript is an interpreted language executed by the user's browser, not the server. PHP is also executed at the server-side and that `include` function has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Now, to port that behaviour to JSP you would use a [JSP tag](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jsp%20tags&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CEYQFjAD&url=http://www.jsptut.com/tags.jsp&ei=MopGUIGgC9Ok0AX0yIGQBA&usg=AFQjCNFLdEoszg2ewhWSEJ0b1aEjf0XwLQ), more specifically, the [`<jsp:include />`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/1.2/syntaxref1214.html) tag:

```
<jsp:include page="array.jsp" />
```

But if what you are trying to is to link your JSP with a JavaScript file then you should use a better option which consist of using the standard HTML `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="array.js" />
```

Comment: I have an Html file in where you insert some data and when you click submit on form it executes a Php file.In that Php file i use the include order,in order to load the array.php and use it to return the result i want back on Html file.                                                    Now imagine that i have to do this,on Javascript and also on Jsp.From what i unerstand i can do this in Jsp with the Jsp tag you posted? But how about on Javascript? Is there away? perhaps having less than three files etc?

Comment: I can't really figure out the requirements that force you to have your code split on so many files but yes, the `<jsp:include>` tag would do that for you. In JavaScript there is no standard way of including a file into another.